# ARC lifetime during property access

Tags: swift, automatic-ref-counting

Suppose I have two classes and two functions like this:

```
public class DataContainer {
    let someData = NSMutableData()
}
public class SuperContainer {
    let someDataContainer = DataContainer()
}

func subFunc(someDataContainer: DataContainer) {
    // Is someSuperContainer guaranteed to be alive?
    // Or may it have been released and only someDataContainer is still alive,
    //    because someSuperContainer is not referenced anymore? 

    ... do something with someDataContainer ...
}
func superFunc() {
    let someSuperContainer = SuperContainer()
    subFunc(someSuperContainer.someDataContainer)
}
```

Is `someSuperContainer` guaranteed to be alive until `subFunc` returns or may it become released after `subFunc` was entered because it's not referenced anymore?

---

**Edit:**
Better example (I tried to keep the question generic but now I think it's better to include a real-world-like example):

```
public class DataContainer {
    let someData = NSMutableData()
    deinit {
        memset_s(someData.mutableBytes, someData.length, 0x00, someData.length)
    }
}

func doSomethingWithData(data: NSMutableData) {
    // Is DataContainer guaranteed to be still alive?
    // Or may it have been released and `data` zeroed-out,
    //    because someSuperContainer is not referenced anymore
    //    (and was deinitialized and released)? 

    ... do something with data ...
}
func someFunc() {
    let dataContainer = DataContainer()
    doSomethingWithData(dataContainer.someData)
}
```

Comment: This "real-world-like" example illustrates why this pattern is problematic. You've allocated your `DataContainer`, which in turn allocated a `NSMutableData`, passed it to `doSomethingWithData`, and then lets `DataContainer` fall out of scope and be deallocated, calling its `deinit` while `doSomethingWithData` might be using the data asynchronously.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Any variable or class is available and alive until its scope ends. In your case, someSuperContainer has a scope of superFunc.  When superFunc ends, then so will someSuperContainer.

```
func superFunc() {
    let someSuperContainer = SuperContainer()
    subFunc(someSuperContainer.someDataContainer)
    // someSuperContainer will cease to exist once this func completes.
}
```

Comment: Thank you  
Btw., have you any official source?

Comment: https://developer.apple.com/library/prerelease/ios/documentation/Swift/Conceptual/Swift_Programming_Language/Declarations.html

Comment: Minor clarification: Technically, in ARC, an object is deallocated when there no more strong references to it. In this case, there are no other strong references to it and when it falls out of scope, the last strong reference is removed and will therefore be deallocated. But if `subFunc` was refactored to take the super container as a parameter and maintained a strong reference to it until the request was done, then it wouldn't be deallocated until that last strong reference was resolved.

Comment: But the last strong reference is only removed if the program leaves the scope, not after the last use in the scope?

Comment: Dont get me wrong: ryantxr's description is largely correct given your example. In this example, there is only one reference to this  `SuperContainer` instance, so it will be deallocated as soon it falls out of scope. But there are plenty of examples where objects have further strong references (or make copy and keep reference to that) that are established and maintained by methods you might call (AFNetworking's `AFHTTPSessionManager` is an example). If you describe practical example what you're really trying to do, we can suggest refactoring that will accomplish what you want.

Comment: Ah, now I see your point  
I already have some experience with ARC and what it does; I just wanted to know when references are decremented (decremented after last occurrence in the scope or decremented after the scope ends).
The question came to my mind as I thought about a deinit-function of SuperContainer to zero-out all bytes of it's SubContainer. If the deinit-function would have been called immediately after I enter subFunc, the data would be destroyed before I could work with it. I'll edit my question to include this.

Comment: @K.Biermann - Yep, your new example is a wonderful illustration of how you can get into serious trouble with this pattern. Very, very dangerous (if doing anything asynchronously, anyway).